# How do I solve the differential equation $r(t)^2 + r^{'}(t)^2 = 1$, where $r$ is a smooth real-valued function?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> How do I solve the differential equation $r(t)^2 + r^{'}(t)^2 = 1$, where $r: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a smooth real-valued function ?

In Calculus I've seen linear (higher-order) differential equations, but never equations where the functions involved are squared.

However, in some other mathematical textbook, I'm reading, the differential equation above is to be found.

Can I use my knowledge from Calculus to solve differential equation completely for all solutions ? Please show me how or describe the process.

Comment: Note that $dr/dt = \pm\sqrt{1-r^2}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Nearly a duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485115/finding-a-non-constant-solution-to-x2x2-9

Comment: This question is related to [this earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1120291/166535) by the OP. I provided this sketchy solution in a comment: $(dr/dt)^2+r^2=1\implies dr/dt=\sqrt{1-r^2}\implies$ $dr/\sqrt{1-r^2}=dt\implies\int dr/\sqrt{1-r^2}=\int dt\implies$ $\arcsin(r)=t+C\implies r=\sin(t+C)$. I take it that the OP wants more details.

Comment: How do I argue that $\sin(t+C)$ is the unique solution ? I've tried considering $(\frac {y} {\sin(t+C)})'$ is $y$ is another solution etc.

Comment: There are uniqueness and existence theorems for ODEs: [example pdf](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf). I would suggest trying to use that general machinery rather than doing something more ad hoc.